# GTK style widget error in cv2

Tags: python, gtk, opencv

I wrote a script which perfectly runs in Windows.

This is the script:

```
import imutils
import cv2
from imutils.video import VideoStream

vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()

while True:
    frame = vs.read()
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
```

Please ignore that I have not added the `q` for quit etc.

But I was trying it out in Ubuntu 20.04 and it throws the following error in the terminal and also my system freezes/lags for a second or two;

```
(python:43358): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 03:48:45.885: IA__gtk_widget_style_get: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
```

This line repeats for sometime and then the process is killed and the following is shown in the terminal:

```
(python:43358): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 03:48:45.885: IA__gtk_widget_style_get: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Killed
```

In the process I do not see any webcam footage or anything on my screen, nor any window opens. Its just the terminal displaying errors.
I am not using any themes etc.

Any sort of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had opencv installed using conda.

After removing it using

```
conda remove opencv
```

I installed it using pip

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Works fine now.

In windows however, there is no such issue. Conda and pip both work well.